# Select the 5 bests from 5 categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `userpage` with the fields `id`, `userid` and `pageid`. There's a table `page` with fields `id` and `categoryid` as well.

With `userpage`, I link users to pages. This can happen only once for one combination. What I now want is an SQL query that can return something like this:

```
Category 1   1623 | Category 2  1105 | ... | Category 5   980
------------------+------------------+-----+-----------------
Page 1        512 | Page 6       403 | ... | Page 11      280
Page 2        488 | Page 7       320 | ... | Page 12      260
...           ... | ...          ... | ... | ...          ...
Page 5        105 | Page 10      110 | ... | Page 15       56
```

The numbers are the numbers of links a page has. The numbers next to the categories are the totals. These totals may be calculated as the sum of the five best pages or of all the pages, that doesn't matter that much.

The pages have to be ordered descending by linkcount.
The categories have to be ordered descending by total linkcount.

How can I make MySQL return only the five best pages from the five best categories? Is that even possible using pure SQL.

Note: this is how I want to have it on the front-end, the data may be returned in a different way. The most important is that I get the numbers and just the pages and categories I need.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but a few things are unclear to me. The way you show the results make it look like category's are seperate columns. Is this intented?

Comment: @NLwino sorry for the unclarity and thanks for your reply! This is only how I want to have it on the front-end, the data may be returned in a different way. The most important is that I get the numbers and just the pages and categories I need. Does that clarify things up?